# Timed out retrying. Expected to find element but never found it. Failed on CI

Tags: testing, timeout, cypress

I am having an issue in Github Actions.
I am using Cypress to test the frontend of my app, and everything is working perfectly in the Cypress app.
But when I am pushing everything on master in GitHub and run the test via Github Actions, every now and then, the same flaky test is failing with he following error.

`Timed out retrying after 5000ms: Expected to find element "xxx" but never found it.`

This line is the problematic one:

`cy.purposeElement("delete_user_dialog").should('be.visible')`

The element we are talking about takes 0.2s to appear with a fade-in animation.
My guess is that the page was slow to respond, while Cypress was fast to act.
How can I avoid solve a flaky test like that?

I could use a `cy.wait` but it is not recommended and I do not want to increase the time of the test.
Plus, the result is as flaky.

Comment: Could you add more detail of the steps before and after the fade-in animation for your test and app? There might be a request you can intercept and wait on.

Comment: We don't know what cy.purposeElement() does. I'd suggest to take a look at screenshots from CI. You can store screenshots as artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as increasing the timeout, especially if the test works perfectly when running on the local machine.

```js
cy.purposeElement("delete_user_dialog", {timeout:20_000}).should('be.visible')
```

To be 100% sure, do a burn test which is described here: [Burning Tests with cypress-grep](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/)